# Reentry permit application, purpose of the trip (part 4 of I-131)

Tags: usa

The honest reason for why I would like to apply for the reentry permit as a US LPR (Part 4 in I-131) is reflected by the following:

> I do not intend to leave the US for extended periods of time. I would use the reentry permit to travel back to the US in case I lose my passport.

Does this sound OK or should I come up with smth better?

Comment: You can enter the US without a passport (only the Green Card), you don't need a I-131

Comment: Yes but if I get stuck in some other country I may not be able to board a plane without a passport or  travel document. Reentry permit, on the contrary, can even be used for obtaining a visa, in case if I need transit through another country.

Comment: I may well be misunderstanding the application form, but to me [Part4](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-131.pdf) is about the purpose of your travel *outside* the US, *not* why you would be returning *to* the US. In any event, why would you invent ‘something better’ rather than answering honestly?

Comment: Well I interpreted this part more as "The purpose of getting the reentry permit". Are you suggesting that I should indicate the actual reason for a short travel, smth like "visiting friends" or "business"?

Comment: The form asks for ‘Purpose of trip’ and ‘List the countries you intend to visit’. If ‘visiting friends’ is the purpose, that’s what I’d write. Seems clear to me, either I’m misunderstanding something (I’m not a US resident) or you’re over-thinking it, IMHO

Comment: Having a reentry permit is not required for LPRs in order to enter the US. It is normally obtained if a person intends to leave the country for more than a year. In this case, when applying for the permit, people typically provide explanations for their extended leave.

Comment: @mavzolej I get that. The explanation could still be ‘visiting friends’ or ‘business’ or whatever, my point was that honesty is better than ‘coming up with something’

Comment: "if I get stuck in some other country I may not be able to board a plane without a passport or travel document": TIMATIC recognizes that a green card is sufficient, so you would at least be able to fly directly to the US without a re-entry permit as long as you haven't been away for more than a year.  "Reentry permit, on the contrary, can even be used for obtaining a visa, in case if I need transit through another country": which countries issue visas on a US reentry permit?  The normal procedure for a lost or stolen passport is to get a new one from your country of citizenship.

Comment: The US government allows airlines to board green card holders for a flight to the US without a passport. See the [CBP carrier information guide](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2023-Nov/Carrier%20Information%20Guide%20ENGLISH.pdf), page 32: "A Lawful Permanent Resident may travel to the United States without a passport with a Permanent Resident Card (Form I-551)." Are you worried that an airline will refuse to board you without a passport anyway?

Comment: I think if you have any legitimate purpose, USCIS will be happy to take your money and issue you the re-entry permit. That said, if you're willing to spend hundreds of dollars every 2 years to renew your re-entry permit, you're better off just spending the money for rush service to replace your lost passport (should that ever happen).

Comment: This sounds reassuring, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Reentry permit is not a substitute for your national passport, it is a permit to return after a prolonged absence as an LPR.

If you don't intend to stay outside the US for more than a year then you don't need the permit or the passport, you just need your green card.

If a passport is required by other countries, the reentry permit won't help anyway. If you lose your national passport - reach out to your nearest consulate for a replacement. If you lose your green card - reach out to the nearest US consulate for assistance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._re-entry_permit To my understanding, in certain cases, similarly to the refugee travel document, the reentry permit can be used for visa issuance purposes.

Comment: @mavzolej from the article it seems like only one country has explicitly said that they accept it, and some others implicitly accept it as a travel document. It may be considered as a laissez-passer,  or an emergency passport, but these have much stricter restrictions than national passport and you'd need to have a lot of explaining to do as to why you're using it. Usually, I-131 travel documents are used for visas only by refugees or otherwise stateless persons. It will raise a lot of flags if you use it the way you intend.

Comment: See also [this document](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/guides/B5en.pdf): "You may also want to get a reentry permit if you plan on traveling outside the United States and cannot or do not wish to get a passport from your home country. Many countries throughout the world may allow you to use a reentry permit much like you would use a passport—placing necessary visas and entry and exit stamps in the permit—so you may use it as your main travel document. Be sure to check with any country you plan to visit about specific requirements before you travel."